# C code for sensor prints output only once and exits

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, sensors

Im a C noob, Ive this code which is supposed to measure body temperature using IR sensor on raspberry pi.
The code is working fine but it doesn't work in loop mode and simply prints the temperature only once and exits.
While I want it to run continuously until user presses some interrupt key/killed by user.

```
//gcc mlx90614.c -o mlx90614 -l bcm2835
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#define AVG 1   //averaging samples
 
 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char buf[6];
    unsigned char i,reg;
    double temp=0,calc=0, skytemp,atemp;
    bcm2835_init();
    bcm2835_i2c_begin();
    bcm2835_i2c_set_baudrate(25000);
    // set address
    bcm2835_i2c_setSlaveAddress(0x5a);
 
    printf("\ndevice is working!!\n");
 
    calc=0;
    reg=7;
 
    for(i=0;i<AVG;i++)
    {
        bcm2835_i2c_begin();
        bcm2835_i2c_write (&reg, 1);
        bcm2835_i2c_read_register_rs(&reg,&buf[0],3);
        temp = (double) (((buf[1]) << 8) + buf[0]);
        temp = (temp * 0.02)-0.01;
        temp = temp - 273.15;
        calc+=temp;
        sleep(1);
    }
 
    skytemp=calc/AVG;
    calc=0;
    reg=6;
 
    for(i=0;i<AVG;i++){
        bcm2835_i2c_begin();
        bcm2835_i2c_write (&reg, 1);
        bcm2835_i2c_read_register_rs(&reg,&buf[0],3);
        temp = (double) (((buf[1]) << 8) + buf[0]);
        temp = (temp * 0.02)-0.01;
        temp = temp - 273.15;
        calc+=temp;
        sleep(1);
    }
 
    atemp=calc/AVG;
 
    printf("ambient temperature = %04.2f\n", atemp);
    printf("object temperature = %04.2f\n", skytemp);
 
    printf("done\n");
 
    return 0;
}
```

To compile

```
gcc mlx90614.c -o mlx90614 -l bcm2835
sudo ./mlx90614
```

Output

```
device is working!!
ambient temperature = 30.06
object temperature=31.04
done
```

Comment: Curious: Why use `<< +` (logical, arithmetic ops) with `((buf[1]) << 8) + buf[0]` instead of `* +` or `<< |`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an infinite loop.  For example:

```
printf("\ndevice is working!!\n");
while(1)
{
    calc=0;
    reg=7;
    ...
    printf("ambient temperature = %04.2f\n", atemp);
    printf("object temperature = %04.2f\n", skytemp);
}
printf("done\n");
```

Comment: You could remove the `printf("done\n");` as the program never gets there.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That's true.  I was just using this to mark the end of the loop block.

Comment: Also `while(1)` should be `while(ButtonNotPressd())` etc...

Comment: @Jabberwocky The button press referred to is `CTRL-C`, right?

Comment: I don't know which button the OP refers to. If it's Ctrl+C, `while(1)` is OK. If it's some other button on his whatever board he has, then it needs to be done differently. I upvoted anyway.

Comment: There's a break somewhere in the ... section.